# Angular, PrimeNG - p-dropdown rendered unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG in my Angular application. I'm intending to use the p-dropdown component, but it is rendering very strangely in my components.

[image: p-dropdown strange render]

This looks nothing like what they demonstrate in their documentation.

Here is package.json. (Perhaps Bootstrap and PrimeNG versioning are misaligned or some such?):

```
{
  "name": "soar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
 <form [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p-dropdown [options]="productionSelectItems" formControlName="productionId"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using Bootstrap app-wide, but I wouldn't imagine that'd be a problem. Full-disclosure: I'm not a UI/UX person, but I think this should instead be rendered as some sort of `select` element. What may be causing this and how do I fix it?

The data is not the problem. `Hello World!` here is one `SelectItem` I've hard-coded. It has a value of 1 and it's label is `Hello World!`

Comment: Full-disclosure: I didn't downvote the question - but totally agree with downvote. First, what do you mean *strangely* and *unexpectedly*? In order to help you one needs to look at your Angular code (what is the content of productionSelectItems). package.json is totally useless.

Comment: the content of select item is not the problem @Felix. there is one SelectItem i've hard-coded to show "Hello World" as the label and 1 as the value...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by importing PrimeNG and Primeicons styles into my project's `styles.scss` file:

```
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"; 
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
```

After having done this, the dropdown looks similar to how it is demonstrated in PrimeNG documentation:

[image: p-dropdown with imported styles]